# Pandas merge two time series dataframes based on time window (cut/bin/merge)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

Having a 750k rows `df` with 15 columns and a `pd.Timestamp` as `index` called `ts`.
I process realtime data down to milliseconds in near-realtime.

Now I would like to apply some statistical data derived from a higher time resolution  in `df_stats` as new columns to the big `df`. The `df_stats` has a time resolution of 1 minute.

```
$ df
+----------------+---+---------+
| ts             | A | new_col |
+----------------+---+---------+
| 11:33:11.31234 | 1 | 81      |
+----------------+---+---------+
| 11:33:11.64257 | 2 | 81      |
+----------------+---+---------+
| 11:34:10.12345 | 3 | 60      |
+----------------+---+---------+
```

```
$ df_stats
+----------------+----------------+
| ts             | new_col_source |
+----------------+----------------+
| 11:33:00.00000 | 81             |
+----------------+----------------+
| 11:34:00.00000 | 60             |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Currently I have the code below, but it is inefficient, because it nees to iterate over the complete data.

I am wondering if there couldnt be an easier solution using `pd.cut`, `bin` or `pd.Grouper`? Or something else to merge the time-buckets on the two indexes?

```
df_stats['ts_timeonly'] = df.index.map(lambda x: x.replace(second=0, microsecond=0))
df['ts_timeonly'] = df.index.map(lambda x: x.replace(second=0, microsecond=0))
df = df.merge(df_stats, on='ts_timeonly', how='left', sort=True, suffixes=['', '_hist']).set_index('ts')
```

Comment: Did you try `pd.merge_asof` [asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try something new `reindex`

```
df_stats=df_stats.set_index('ts').reindex(df['ts'], method='nearest')
df_stats.index=df.index

df=pd.concat([df,df_stats],axis=1)
```

Or

```
df=pd.merge_asof(df, df_stats, on='ts',direction='nearest')
```

Comment: Needed to solve a `TypeError: No matching signature found).` in before by getting both columns on same `dtype` and than `pd.merge_asof` works. It works well, but isnt very fast. I tried it with indexes as well: `pd.merge_asof(df,df_stats, left_index=True, right_index=True, direction='backward')`. Will try your other solution now.

Comment: Had a lot of stuff open in the debugger and tried it standalone again. `pd.merge_asof` works very fast by using the mentioned arguments. Done - Thanks!

Comment: @gies0r great ~ happy coding ~